# Title background with grid.arrange() of ggplot objects

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've made a couple of simple plots with ggplot2 and grouped them with `grid.arrange()` (from package grid.extra) to join the plots in one single figure.
I'm creating the title via the `grid.arrange()` function with argument `top`, as below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
```

...

```
tiff("Figure5.tiff",
     height = 20, width = 16, units = "cm", 
     compression = "lzw", res = 300)
Fig5 <- grid.arrange(plot5, plot5Ran, ncol = 2,
                     top = textGrob("Comparison of Correlation Output",
                                  gp = gpar(fill='snow')))

plot(Fig5)
dev.off()
```

[image: Partial screenshot, background of title is same as plot, rather than white margin]

However, as you can see on the partial screenshot above, the background of the title (the portion of the image at the top of the figure, added by argument `top`, gets the background from the ggplot theme rather than being white like the margins.
I've tried using argument `fill` but to no effect.

How can I get the title over a white background?
I know that using `facets` would be more straightforward and avoid `grid.arrange`, but it doesn't make sense in this case. I guess that I could also change the `ggplot` theme to white, but that's not an option in this case. 
Thanks

Comment: if you supply some reproducible data it will be easier for us to play around with it to help you

Comment: it will also help if you provide the actual code to generate plot5 and plot5Ran

Comment: also, ``top=)`` that doesn't seem correct...probably not relate to your issue though...Also, using made up data (iris) I wasn't able to reproduce your issue. It would also help if you post your ``sessionInfo``. For more help on providing reproducible examples see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you for the tips. @user20650 is correct, replacing `plot(Fig5)` by `Fig5` fixed the issue.

Comment: grid.arrange() draws directly, no need to print() it, or worse plot() it (gtable::plot.gtable is the reason you're seeing a weird background -- it was meant for debugging purpose apparently)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user20650 suggested, it was a printing problem.
Both options below work.

First saving the figure as R object and the tiff file:

```
tiff("Figure5X.tiff",
     height = 20, width = 16, units = "cm", 
     compression = "lzw", res = 300)
Fig5 <- grid.arrange(plot5, plot5Ran, ncol = 2,
                     top = "Comparison of Correlation Output")
Fig5
dev.off()
```

Or, saving the tiff file only, as suggested by user20650:

```
tiff("Figure5Y.tiff",
     height = 20, width = 16, units = "cm", 
     compression = "lzw", res = 300)
     grid.arrange(plot5, plot5Ran, ncol = 2,
                     top = "Comparison of Correlation Output")
dev.off()
```